# How to translate by adding the locale in the URL.I18next

Tags: reactjs

Need some help. I'm kinda stuck with the translation process. I'm trying to translate my page into Arabic, English and Spanish. The translations are working. The default languages is "English". When the language is switched the URL should contain locale based on the translated language. URLS should be rewritten with /en , /es or /ar.

As it is said in the i18n documentation, already created files in the public with the name locales which contain the whole translations needed.Then i18n file is created.

This is my code:

```
import i18n from "i18next"; 

import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

const languages = ["en",  "es", "ar"]

const options = {
    order: ['localStorage', 'querystring',  'navigator',],

    lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
    lookupCookie: 'i18next',
    lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    lookupSessionStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
    lookupFromSubdomainIndex: 0,

    caches: [ 'localStorage', 'cookie', ],
    excludeCacheFor: ['cimode'],

    cookieMinutes: 10,
    cookieDomain: 'myDomain',

    htmlTag: document.documentElement,

    cookieOptions: { path: '/', sameSite: 'strict' }
}

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: "ar",
        lng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        whitelist: languages,
        checkWhitelist: true ,
        detection: options,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        }
    });

export default i18n;
```

In the Router.js File

```
<Route
        exact
        path="/services/edit/:lng"
        render={(routeProps) => {
          return (
            <MainLayout   >
              <ServicesEdit {...routeProps} isEdit />
            </MainLayout>
          );
        }}
      />
```

in The MenuContent.jsx file

```
<Menu.Item key="2" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
        <Link to={`/services/edit/${lng}`}>{props.t("SERVICES_EDIT_PAGE")}</Link>
 </Menu.Item>
```

The DropDownMenu.jsx.The handleClick function passed via props is

```
  let handleClick = (lng) => {

    i18n.changeLanguage(lng)

  }

 <Menu>
            <Menu.Item>
                <a onClick={() => props.handleClick("en")} >
                    <div>
                        <span className="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span>
                        English
                    </div>
                </a>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item >
                <a onClick={() => props.handleClick("es")} >
                    <div>

                        <span className="flag-icon flag-icon-es"></span>

                        Spanish
                    </div>
                </a>
            </Menu.Item>
            
            <Menu.Item>
                <a onClick={() => props.handleClick("ar")} >

                    <div>

                        <span className="flag-icon flag-icon-ae"></span>

                        العربية
                   </div>

                </a>
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

When referring to `/en`, `/es` and `/fr`, you are actually talking about the `path`. However, the `path` detection is not set up in your language detector settings.

Change the configuration like so:

```
// add 'path' to the order Array
order: ['localStorage', 'querystring',  'navigator', 'path'],

// change 'lookupFromPathIndex' to -1 so the last element is used
lookupFromPathIndex: -1,
```

**Edit:**

It looks like you can't set `lookupFromPathIndex` to `-1`. This uses a plain Array lookup and will yield `undefined`. If you really want to use the last path index for the locale, you'll have to add a custom detector.

Add the following custom detector:

**src/i18n/customPath.js**

```
export default {
  name: 'customPath',

  lookup() {
    let found;
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const language = window.location.pathname.match(/\/([a-zA-Z-]*)/g);
      if (language instanceof Array && language.length) {
        found = language[language.length - 1].replace('/', '');
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
};
```

**Register the detector:**

```
import customPath from './customPath.js';

const languageDetector = new LanguageDetector();

languageDetector.addDetector(customPath);

const options = {
    order: ['customPath', 'localStorage', 'querystring',  'navigator'],
    // reset of options
};

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(languageDetector) // <-- point to the variable
```

Comment: languageDetector.addDetector(myDetector).Sorry , in the above example mydetector is not defined. Where i should import customPath?

Comment: Did the same way as it is said. When the language is switched to another language the path is not changes  automatically to  "/ar"...

Comment: This is only the "detection" script, if you want to update the URL you will have to listen to the `languageChanged` event and update the URL accordingly.